# Why is Kullback–Leibler divergence a divergence. How is it related to divergence of a vector field?

Tags: vector-analysis

Why is Kullback–Leibler divergence a divergence. How is it related to divergence of a vector field

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [the vector calculus concept's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) opens

> This article is about divergence in vector calculus. For divergence of
>   infinite series, see [Divergent
>   series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series). For
>   divergence in statistics, see [Divergence
>   (statistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(statistics)).
>   For other uses, see [Divergence
>   (disambiguation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_(disambiguation)).

and KL is an example of a divergence in statistics and [its own article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) opens

> Not to be confused with
>   [divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) in [vector
>   calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus).

I think the names are unrelated. There are just too many times in the history of mathematics terminology someone has needed a name that conveys a difference between things.